# how do i know when to use "in" and "on"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

i mean when i'm not talking about places or time like in these examples:
Using "on":

> On that subject she was adamant.
>
> His contemplative regard fell on Carmen
>
> It's about time you spent some money on yourself.
>
> Pressing on the scar, he winced.

Now with "in":

> He was such a wonderful person in so many ways.
>
> As it came to a stop the conductor called out in a loud voice.
>
> He put a spoon in her hand.
>
> Somehow it simply wasn't top priority in her life right now.
>
> "It's okay," he said in a flippant tone.

Comment: Most of your examples are idiomatic expressions that you just have to learn. Frequently, the choice of preposition is a guide to the action. You can **Press in, press on, press up, press down** and so on, although some of these are set **prepositional verbs**, whose meaning is often not clear from their construction.

Comment: Quite true. I would like to know what is Camilo's (OP) native language, and whether he/she can translate all the prepositions (or case inflections) so easily. This stuff is insanely idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think most of these are idioms, and you just have to read and listen as much as you can to learn by example whether to use on or in.